# How to run a ReactJS application at startup on Beaglebone?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, autorun

My main computer is running Ubuntu 18,04, I developed an application on **ReactJS** on FrontEnd, **NodeJS** on BackEnd and **MySQL** concerning the database ON beaglebone.  .

More information about my BeagleBone :

```
 root@beaglebone:~# uname -a
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone71.1 #162 SMP Fri Oct 16 07:27:34 CST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I want to run my application   always at startup on **BeagleBone**

What can I do to make a script run as soon as it boots up ?

Comment: This question is missing some further details, like which operating system (and version) is running on the device, which packages have you already installed, what you are trying to achieve with the "script", as that might not be the actual "solution".

Comment: Please note that this looks like a very old image, judging by the kernel. I'd strongly recommend to use an up to date image from http://beagleboard.org/latest-images as the basis for your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Just like on any other device (including PC or Server) that runs a Linux distribution.**

Some quick pointers:

- [Latest BeagleBone Images](http://beagleboard.org/latest-images) are Debian 9.4 based
- Use an "IoT" image unless you *really* need the HDMI (or LCD) output and accept the lower performance.
- Debian uses *systemd* to manage automatic starting and stopping of software services
- Create a [systemd service file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) that invokes a process you need (e.g. npm) as the desired user (probably 'debian'). There seem to be helper tools like [service-systemd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-systemd)
- reload systemd `systemctl daemon-reload` to make it aware of the new file
- enable it `systemctl enable myfancy.service`
- Both flavours of mySQL on Debian (`mysql-server` and `mariadb-server`) come with a systemd file already.

Comment: http://mybeagleboneblackfindings.blogspot.com/2013/10/running-script-on-beaglebone-black-boot.html, like that ?

Comment: Yes, or use the [service-systemd nodejs module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-systemd)

Comment: Where I put this  service-systemd nodejs module  ? on autorun folder ?

Comment: The page I linked gives a basic usage example. It also links to the full documentation: https://github.com/braceslab/service-systemd/blob/HEAD/doc/README.md

Comment: Thanks @TBR, it works well. Can you up the post please ?

Comment: What do you mean by `"Can you up the post please?"`

Comment: I want post an question on stackoverflow, but I get : `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.
Related` and I have `unaccept` to this post .

Comment: I'd recommend to further improve your question. Which should be easier as you can look back at how you eventually did it. I'll be then happy to upvote your question.

Comment: Thanks @TBR, you make me to post a question.